# Using number variables with i18next.t() for generating gettext .po files

Tags: reactjs, gettext, i18next

I'm in the process of generating `.po` files for translators. I'm currently doing this in my React app by using `i18next` to generate a `translation.json` file and then using `i18next-conv` to convert that to a `.po` file.

I'm using the `gettext` approach where my key is basically the English string that I want to convert. This is working great but there are some use cases where I'm concerned for flexibility.

For example, I have a date of birth error field where if the person is younger than `12` years old we will show the user: `"Must be 12 years or older!"`.

So currently I just use: `i18next.t('Must be 12 years or older!')`

I want to know if I could make that `12` a variable so that there's a template for this translation. Eg. what if the age value there was a variable provided by the backend, how to do make that a variable using that current standard that I'm taking?

Comment: This might help you as a starting point: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation

Comment: Yeah thanks, I have had a look at that and I wasn't really sure how to use that to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to sort it out by writing the following:

```
i18next.t('Must Be {{minAge}} Years Or Older', { minAge: MIN_AGE })
```

Where `MIN_AGE` is the variable.

This seems to work great, then in the `.po` file that line looks like this:

```
msgid "Must Be {{minAge}} Years Or Older"
msgstr "Must Be {{minAge}} Years Or Older"
```

And the `.json` file converts to this:

```
{
  "Must Be {{minAge}} Years Or Older": "Must Be {{minAge}} Years Or Older"
}
```

And the resulting text when `MIN_AGE=16` renders `"Must Be 16 Years Or Older"` as expected.